# How to efficiently get price & id from google analytics through bigQuery

Tags: sql, google-analytics, google-bigquery

I trying to create a query that exacts a couple of parameters from the iap event I can't seem to get it working as I want. I've tried a couple of different ways but have seen performance issues when looking at multiple days. Below is my latest attempt and seems to be quickest although I feel its the wrong approach. Any suggestions would be helpful.

```
    with purchase_id as (
        SELECT event_timestamp, param.value.string_value as product_id
        FROM `XXX.analytics_X.events_20210803`,
        UNNEST(event_params) AS param
        WHERE event_name = "in_app_purchase"
        AND (param.key = "product_name")
    ),
     purchase_price as (
        SELECT event_timestamp, param.value.int_value as product_price
        FROM `XXX.analytics_X.events_20210803`,
        UNNEST(event_params) AS param
        WHERE event_name = "in_app_purchase"
        AND (param.key = "price")
    )

SELECT event_timestamp, product_id, product_price 

FROM purchase_id as pid 
JOIN purchase_price as pp
ON pid.event_timestamp = pp.event_timestamp
```

The result I'm looking for is a single row per event with the relevant params in.

| timestamp | product_id | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1627860223322000 | fun_times | 10 |
| 1627860223432000 | old_times | 3 |

It's a standard google analytics table but for completeness see the screen shot.

[image: Table View]

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of the logic you want implemented.  A question without an explanation of the data is pretty hard to understand.

Comment: Sorry I was just adding a screen shot. Its just a standard google analytics table.

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented this, which reads better and is marginally quicker:

```
SELECT event_timestamp,

(SELECT value.int_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) 
    WHERE key = "price" LIMIT 1) AS product_price,
(SELECT value.string_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) 
    WHERE key = "product_id" LIMIT 1) AS product_id,


FROM `XXX.analytics_X.events_20210803`
WHERE event_name = "in_app_purchase"
```

To help others out check this article, really helpful. I must have missed it first time round.

https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-use-select-from-unnest-to-analyze-multiple-parameters-in-bigquery-for-analytics-5838f7a004c2

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it is to use the pattern `SELECT <..> FROM UNNEST(<..>)`.

If you plan to use this pattern multiple times in your query, you can define a `TEMP FUNCTION` to make it look cleaner:

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION GetParamValue(params ANY TYPE, target_key STRING)
AS (
  (SELECT `value` FROM UNNEST(params) WHERE key = target_key LIMIT 1)
);

SELECT
  event_timestamp,
  GetParamValue(event_params, 'product_id').string_value AS product_id,
  GetParamValue(event_params, 'product_price').int_value AS product_price
FROM <Your_table>
WHERE event_name = 'in_app_purchase';
```

You can use the same temp function for `user_properties` as well.